# How to have multiple inserts in one sql query that uses the identities from the previous table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data into many tables in one SQL Server stored procedure. I am also using the identities from the tables that I have inserted data into to then resolve the many to many relationship by writing those identities to another table.

In theory the logic seems to be there for the stored procedure, but on execution only the first insert statement has been executed. Please could anyone assist with this.

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[InsertAllCustomerDetails]
(
    --@CustomerID Bigint output,
    @Firstname varchar(100),
    @LastName varchar(100),
    @Initials varchar(10),
    @Title varchar(20),
    @DateCreated datetime,
    @isDeleted Bit,
    --@ContactNumberID BIGINT Output,
    @ContactNumber Varchar(100),
    @ContactTypeID bigint,
    @Street Varchar(550),
    @AreaID BIGINT,
    @isPreferred Bit
    --@AddressID Bigint OutPut
)
AS

Insert Into Customer
(
    FisrtName,
    LastName,
    Initials,
    [Title],
    DateCreated,
    isDeleted
)
Values
(
    @Firstname,
    @LastName,
    @Initials,
    @Title,
    @DateCreated,
    @isDeleted
)
Declare @CustomerID BIGINT 
SELECT   @CustomerID = @@IDENTITY
       RETURN @CustomerID
--This will now insert the contact details for the customer
Insert Into ContactNumber
(
    ContactNumber,
    ContactTypeID
)
Values
(
    @ContactNumber,
    @ContactTypeID
)
Declare @ContactNumberID BIGINT 
SELECT   @ContactNumberID = @@IDENTITY
--This will insert into the CustomerContactNumber
Insert Into CustomerContactNumber
(
    ContactNumberID,
    CustomerID
)
Values
(
    @ContactNumberID,
    @CustomerID
)
--This will insert the address
Insert Into [Address]
(
    Street,
    AreaID,
    isPreferred
)
Values
(
    @Street,
    @AreaID,
    @isPreferred
)
Declare @AddressID BIGINT 
SELECT   @AddressID = @@IDENTITY
--This will insert the relationship for the customer Address table
Insert into CustomerAddress
(
    CustomerID,
    AddressID
)
Values
(
    @CustomerID,
    @AddressID
)
```

Comment: Try using Scope_Identity (Ex: SELECT   @CustomerID = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things:

1. You seem to have a typo in the `Customer` insert:

   ```
   Insert Into Customer
   (
       FisrtName,   <-- should be FirstName?
       LastName,
   ```
2. You are `RETURN`ing after the `Customer` insert - that's why only the first one runs

   ```
   Declare @CustomerID BIGINT 
   SELECT   @CustomerID = @@IDENTITY
          RETURN @CustomerID     <----   This exits the sproc
   --This will now insert the contact details for the customer
   Insert Into ContactNumber
   ```

I'm guessing the `RETURN` was there for debugging and not removed since it's obscured by the indentation.

Comment: Thank you so much I thought I was going mad.